# How do I use locales and resource bundles to internationalize my application?

Tags: java

I have a web page which has 3 different languages, Swedish, English and Russian! `WebTexts_en.properties`, `WebTexts_sv.properties` and `WebTexts_ry.properties` files together with `LangSupport.jsp` to chose the Locale for the browser.

My page works in English, `neptune-app-id.appspot.com` but only this language, Swedish and Russian not. Do I need to create a `Internationalization.class` of some kind to get this to work. Or how do I use the locale to work with the resource bundels?

Here are som very good links for this but I do not understand how to make this,

1. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-internationalize-my-web-application.html?page=1
2. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-locales-and-resource-bundles-to-internationalize-my-application.html;jsessionid=72C23BCD47546E9D05DF422DA3F0EC39

Perhaps there is somebody, who knows how to set this up, who can help me with this?

I have included my file setup in Eclipse here for you as well to have a look at. My page are located at http://neptune-app-id.appspot.com/ at Google App Engine.

Comment: Please read this : http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/ . There's a tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html

Comment: I have this error message in my logfile:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.LocalizationContext
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.serialize(SessionManager.java:373)

Comment: Did you u-encode the texts, like `\u202B`?

Comment: I will read this! I'll get back to you again and thank you very much for this...

Comment: u-encode? I my files are encoded in utf-8.

Comment: The encoding of .properties is for historic reasons ISO-8859-1, so you need to use native2ascii.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in Swedish and Rusyn the text is not u-escaped. Java has a small tool to encode and reverse decode texts.

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 native.properties > ascii.properties
```

Otherwise switch files, renaming the Swedish to the English and give that a try.

Comment: The English text open fine in my browser. When a friend open the page in his browser it opens in Swedish text instead. The problem is that the utf-8 do not display Å,Ä,Ö correctly in his browser. I have had this problem before and if i change back to iso-8859 this will work. But the problem now is that i cannot display any language correctly, only English so i am missing something here and i do not really know what?

Comment: I tried to change name but then i get this, ???home.header2??? so it seems he do not find the files some how correctly if i do this???

Comment: What i need to do to be able to change the language from English to Swedish? What is it that makes this change for me? How come the English works and not the Swedish, if English works then must the Swedish must work also some how?

Comment: I looked at your page with `?language=ry` and it looks that UTF-8 was interpreted as ISO-8859-1, the encoding of the .properties files. Try native2ascii.

Comment: Well this is true, all properties files only works with ISO-8859-1. They cannot be encoded with UTF-8, why don't ask me. Still only the English language works so there is still something wrong here. Please have a look the links that change the language one time if they are right or wrongly made?

Comment: This problem is solved now, thank you all for you great help and advise regarding this.